# How can I make the width of ASP.NET menu items the same?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, width

This is the problem:

 [image]

Notice the weird lack of space where a sub-menu item does not have any children, hence the lack of the  ▶  arrow...

Setting the `Width` property of `StaticMenuItemStyle` affects the top-level menu item(s), whereas setting the `Width` property of `DynamicMenuItemStyle` affects the sub-menu items (in this case, everything except the first item *"menu"*).

However, the width of the sub-menu items does not include the width of the  ▶  arrow, and so unfortunately does not appear to be the same width where an item has no children.

Any ideas on how to format this correctly? I would like to keep the arrows if possible...

---

Here is the ASP:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
    Style="text-align: center;">

    <StaticMenuItemStyle Width="200px" BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="White" />
    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="DarkBlue" ForeColor="Yellow" />

    <DynamicMenuItemStyle Width="200px" BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="White" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="DarkBlue" ForeColor="Yellow" />

    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="menu">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="formatting problem!" />

            <asp:MenuItem Text="submenu">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="submenu item 1" />
                <asp:MenuItem Text="submenu item 2" />
                <asp:MenuItem Text="submenu item 3" />
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

---

*Note:  I do know how to correctly format a dropdown menu with an unordered-list and CSS, but I am looking for a purely ASP.NET solution.*

Comment: in which browser are you facing this issue ? i've checked in all browsers and its working fine , now weird space like in your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for checking @AliUmair -- this issue has shown in IE8 and in Firefox 22.0, tested from both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. Are the arrows maybe not appearing for you?

Comment: Okay, so one possible solution is to remove the arrows by adding `StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"` to the `asp:Menu` tag. But I like the arrows though ;)

Comment: Sorry bro I've checked it on IE Tester and it is working fine on all versions :( , I tried to download IE 8 and run it but I'm on Windows 7 it doesn't allows me. But I've been through same problem some years ago, I'll find that code and paste it here, it was a asp.net vertical menu with arrows for sub-menus like your example